# Sqlite 3.8 with pre-Lollipop APIs

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a pre-populated database that i'm trying to copy from `assets` folder.The database uses a few `WITHOUT ROWID` tables which according to [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/withoutrowid.html) work only with SQLite version 3.8.2 (or later versions).

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) SQLite 3.8 is not supported on pre-20 APIs and on those cases i get a "malformed database schema" exception when trying to copy the database.So, is there a way to use SQLite 3.8 on older APIs?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing, by far, is to get rid of `WITHOUT ROWID`.

It is possible to package an independent copy of SQLite with your app. [SQLCipher for Android](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/) is one such packaging. However:

- This adds a few MB to the size of your app, eliminating any savings that you are getting by avoiding `ROWID`
- If for some reason you do not want to use SQLCipher for Android, implementing this yourself is a *lot* of work